# How to disable bookmark navigation in Gravity Forms buttons?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

In multipage forms, when I press the next or back buttons, it goes to the top of the next page form. I need to disable this bevahior.
I check the buttons' settings and conditions, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [gform_confirmation_anchor](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_anchor/) filter.

```
// Update "123" to your form ID.
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor_123', '__return_false' );
```